# QTableWidget set column and get column

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to set programmatically some values of my QTableWidget, but it seems not working.
In my primary thread, I set the table with (PRIMARY_SET):

```
Status="N";
Number = QString::number(x);
Name= "abc;
nrow=i;
QTableWidgetItem *item_Number = new QTableWidgetItem(Number);
QTableWidgetItem *item_Name = new QTableWidgetItem(Name);
QTableWidgetItem *item_Status = new QTableWidgetItem(Status);

QTableWidgetItem *icon_item = new QTableWidgetItem;
QIcon icon("path/to/.png"); 
icon_item->setIcon(icon);
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(nrow, 0, item_Number);
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm->repaint();
ui->centralWidget->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(nrow, 1, icon_item);
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm->repaint();
ui->centralWidget->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(nrow, 2, item_Name);
ui->TabKeyAlarm->repaint();
ui->centralWidget->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(nrow, 3, item_Status);

ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->repaint();
ui->TabKeyAlarm->repaint();
ui->centralWidget->repaint();
```

for n row and it works.

What I have to do after that is to change the icon and the "Status" on particular row if an event happens.
This is my controll in a separated thread, which do not works (CHECK):

```
QTableWidgetItem *_getItem = ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->item(n_MOD,3);
if (_getItem)
    if (_getItem->text() != "K")
        {
            QEvent(QEvent::Type(QEvent::User+5)));
        }
```

It continuosly call the `User+5` event. How can I check if _getItem in row `n_MOD` and column 3 has already "K" text set ? The result is always `_getItem->text()` "no such value"...

Then, this is the code for `User+5` event (SECOND_SET):

```
QString _Status_check="";
Status="K";
QTableWidgetItem *icon_item = new QTableWidgetItem;
QTableWidgetItem *item_Status = new QTableWidgetItem(Status);

while (_Status_check != "K")
{
   QIcon icon("path/to/.png"); 
   icon_item->setIcon(icon);

   ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(n_MOD, 1, icon_item);
   ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->setItem(n_MOD, 3, item_Status);
   _Status_check = ui->TabKeyAlarm_TableED->item(n_MOD,3)->text();
```

I have to use that "while", because otherwise most of the times _Status_check confirm me that the text in row n_MOD column 3 has still the old text...

So my questions are :

1) In CHECK section, how can I check if the element has already the value "K" ?

2) In SECOND_SET section, why it seems that it takes more than one attempt to set the value in row,column?

Comment: 1) `_getItem->text() != "K"` is correct way to check. The problem is somewhere else. 2) You don't need to create new item each time you want to change a text of cell. Just call `pItem-setText();` for it (and the same for icons/styles/...)

Comment: Problem found, thanks. I did not realize that customEvents are different threads, so I had to add a semaphore before the exit from CHECK and wait untill SECOND_SET finishes its job.

Comment: Please close the question to inform everyone that they shouldn't spend their time on this.